# unable to execute an url through curl

Tags: php, curl

I am unable to execute an URL through curl. But if simply run the query thrugh browser, its working fine. My code is like:

```
$xmlData = "<Leads><row no='1'><FL val='First Name'>".$new_fname."</FL><FL val='Last Name'>".$new_lname."</FL><FL val='Email'>".$new_email."</FL><FL val='Phone'>".$new_ph_no."</FL></row></Leads>";
$xmlData = htmlentities($xmlData);
$ch = curl_init("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=XXX&scope=crmapi&xmlData=".$xmlData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);// Turn off the server and peer verification 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_rc4_128_sha'); //for godaddy server patch
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);//Set to return data to string ($response) 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);//Regular post 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

could you please let me know where is the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem/errors you are having?

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see what the problem is

Comment: You make a post request through your browser?

Comment: Please post your error here..

Comment: I got "failed setting cipher list".

Comment: Even if I tried to echo the value of $response, I did not get any value.

Comment: Anybody is there who can help me regarding this issue?

Comment: @Srimanta. Yepp. :) Currently having a working example. But the server returns 400 Bad Request..

Comment: no no in that URL the value of authtoken is dummy.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=XXX&scope=crmapi&xmlData=".$xmlData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// deactivate certificate checking 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);//Set to return data to string ($response) 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);//Regular post 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 

if(!$response) {
    echo curl_error($ch), PHP_EOL;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

After discussion comments I realized that the problem is, that you haven't installed the Thawte ssl certificate on your system. You have two options:

- Install the [certificates](https://www.thawte.com/roots/index.html)
- Disable certificate checking using `CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER = FALSE`

I've used the second approach in my example just to show how to make your code working. For a production system I would advice you to install the certificates.

Comment: I got the following error:
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: But in your scenario, it is showing that "SSL certificate verify ok" but then why it is now showing for me instead I am getting error.

Comment: What operation system are you using? Linux?

Comment: The error you got means, that you didn't have imported the Thawte certificate yet. You have two options: Skip verification or Import that certificate

Comment: I would say best in your case is to just disable the certificate check. Check my update

Comment: Then again I am getting "failed setting cipher list".

Comment: Something with your installation (php, openssl) and or  operating system isn't working as expected. I think then this is a question for http://superuser.com

Comment: After installing certificates, should we switch on CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST 2

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Do you use self signed certificates?

Comment: No I am not using self-signed certs.

Comment: Yes, then you should enable `VERIFYHOST` and `VERIFYPEER`. This will prevent from man in the middle attacks